# With typedef enum, return type enum EnumName produces compiler error when returning an enum member

Tags: objective-c, enums, compiler-errors, typedef, return-type

I have an enum

```
typedef enum {
    kOne,
    kTwo,
    kThree,
    kFour
} Enums;
```

And, in my .h file I have

```
- (enum Enums)getEnum;
```

In my .m file I have

```
- (enum Enums) getEnum {
    return kOne;
}
```

However, I'm getting the error

> Returning 'int' from a function with incompatible result type 'enum Enums'

I'm returning one of the enums so I'm not sure what the error is about.

Answer (score 3):

Your method signature should be:

```
- (Enums)getEnum;
```

Comment: if my signature is `- (Enums)getEnum;` it gives me an error `Expected a type`

Comment: Is the declaration of your enum `typedef enum {...} Enums` in your .h file ? If not, that's where it should go.

Comment: Also remove the extra comma after `kFour`.

Comment: @rmaddy: GCC and Clang allow a final comma in an enumeration.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah but I don't like it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to either get rid of the typedef in `typedef enum {} Enums` or get rid of the `enum` in the method return types.

Answer (score 0):

You only need

```
- (Enums) getEnum;

- (Enums) getEnum {
    return kOne;
}
```

`enum` is used for the definition.

Also Objective-C has the nicer `NS_ENUM` for compile time checking, see [this post](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options) for more info:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Enums) {
    kOne,
    kTwo,
    kThree,
    kFour
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in the .m file it has to be

```
- (Enums) getEnum {
    return kOne;
}
```

but the .h file is still

```
- (enum Enums) getEnum;
```

Comment: No, this isn't true. If your `typedef enum` is also in the .h (and before trying to use it), then you just need `Enums` in both the .h and .m. I do it all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You must name your enum and typedef along with name. You can avoid (Enums) in your definition which looks even more clear.

```
enum enums {
    kOne,
    kTwo,
    kThree,
    kFour
};
```

typedef enum enums Enums;

Now function can be declared as ,

```
Enums getEnum ();
```

and function can be defined as ,

```
Enums getEnum {
    return kOne;
}
```